# Shopify Liquid Objects Not Showing Data

Tags: object, shopify, liquid

I'm having trouble with Shopify objects not bringing data. Example below:

I've added the following object to my header so that I can attempt to detect which page the user is on and then assign different header styles per page:

`{{ page.url }}`

Using the `page` object:

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/page

This doesn't show anything on any pages:

[No Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaeQp.png)

Here's a bigger look at this area of code if required:

[Code View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU69h.png)

Is anybody able to help me understand my error here? Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you trying this on a page type or on a different type? There is a difference between page, collection, index etc.. If you are only after the global URL than use `{{ request.path }}` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'page type' (I'm very new to this). I just put it in the header of my header.liquid section. Either way, `{{ request.path }}` works great for me, thank you. Feel free to put as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shopify have a few different types of pages:

- Pages
- Collections
- Products
- Blogs
- Articles
- Index
- 404
- Search
- Cart
- Account

When you try to say `{{ page.url }}` this takes only URL's of pages that includes `pages` in their URL. For example on `pages/about-us` you will get the URL of that page, but on a page `collections/all` you won't get the URL since that is a different type of page, there you will use `{{ collection.url }}` instead.

The `page` object is valid only on the `page` type.

You can see all the objects here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects